# What are "extended" EXIF attributes and how does the "/exif" block in the query factor into them?

Tags: c#, metadata, exif

I'm working with some legacy code for an application that handles images, including ones with EXIF data. The existing code for querying the metadata includes an undocument "isExtended" parameter that changes the search path:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the Metadata Query string for the specified EXIF property tag
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Target"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <see cref="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719796.aspx"/>
public string EXIFQuery(PropertyTag Target, bool IsExtended)
{
    string s;

    if (IsExtended)
        s = sEXIFRoot + "/exif/{ushort=[ID]}";
    else
        s = sEXIFRoot + "/{ushort=[ID]}";

    return s.Replace("[ID]", ((int)Target).ToString());
}
```

`sEXIFRoot` is defined as "/app1/ifd". I understand that this is building the query for the WIC Metadata Query as per the [linked MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719796.aspx), but why would "isExtended" translate out to including the "/exif" text? Looking at [this article](http://nicholasarmstrong.com/2010/02/exif-quick-reference/), it looks like the standard for accessing EXIF data includes "/exif". Were there earlier formats where this was not the case? The JPEGs I'm working with have the metadata I need in the "/exif" block, but I'm hesitant to change the general call for fear of breaking this if we're looking at older images.

Comment: Consider using a different lib such as my metadata extractor: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet

Comment: @DrewNoakes: Hmm... from your own experience with EXIF data, can you comment why a given attribute may or may not be in an "exif" block?

Comment: Most Exif values are optional. Their presence is largely up to the camera or software provider.

Comment: Ah, so it's basically pretty arbitrary whether it shows up directly under the */aap1/ifd* directory, or under a further *exif* block?